# eval on an argument obtained through `function.__code__.co_varnames` isn't working

Tags: python-3.x

```
def initialize_network(n_inputs, n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_outputs):
     print(eval('n_inputs'))
     perceptron_count = [eval(arg) for arg in initialize_network.__code__.co_varnames[:4]]

initialize_network(1,2,3,4)
```

The above code when executed on my loacal machine produces the error:
`NameError: name 'n_inputs' is not defined`

When executed on Google Colab produces the error:
`NameError: name 'n_hidden1' is not defined`

But, if I do `print(eval('n_inputs'))` or `print(eval('n_hidden1'))` the correct values of the variables get printed.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that a list-comprehension (`[i for i in x]`) is  executed like a sub-function.
Aka:

```
square = [i*i for i in nums]
```

Is executed the same way as:

```
def _s(i):
    return i*i
square = list(map(_s, nums))
```

The `i*i` is executed in an inner-scope.
The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) states: `Note, eval() does not have access to the nested scopes (non-locals) in the enclosing environment.`

`n_inputs` is a variable of the enclosing environment of the list comprehension.
The only value `eval` sees in your example is `arg` and any global variables.

Try the following and you'll see why eval says `n_inputs is not defined`.

```
def my_func(x,y):
    print(locals())
    _ = [print(locals()) for z in range(1)]
```

`locals()` and `globals()` is automatically passed to eval if not explicitly given. But `locals()` inside of the list-comprehension doesn't contain `n_inputs`.

So how to fix? Pass the functions locals to eval.

```
def initialize_network(n_inputs, n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_outputs):
     print(eval('n_inputs'))
     _locals = locals()
     perceptron_count = [eval(arg, globals(), _locals) for arg in initialize_network.__code__.co_varnames[:4]]

initialize_network(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Your answer definitely explained what's happening. So, I'm accepting it.

Comment: But, the solution proposed doesn't work. I'm getting an error `TypeError: eval() takes no keyword arguments`. 

I should probably set the variables `n_inputs, n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_outputs` as global variables to solve the problem I'm facing in the question asked.

Comment: Oh I've misread the documentation in that case... it seems `locals` is a positional only argument. I'll modify the answer accordingly.